# Cannot open Utilities 'FilterOptions'

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to run a code like this in Mathematica:

```
(* initialize everything *)
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Remove["Global`*"]

(* all *nb are in $WorkingDirectory *)
$WorkingDirectory = "/Users/U1/Workspace/BCOASMBH/Core/Fortran/"
(* Load Assumptions and format.m *)
Get[FileNameJoin[{$WorkingDirectory, "TemplateForHamiltonian.nb"}]];
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Get: Cannot open Utilities`FilterOptions`.
Needs: Context Utilities`FilterOptions` was not created when Needs was evaluated.
==========================
Example Script For Writing
==========================
filename = "testing.f" 
stmp = OpenWrite[filename, FormatType -> OutputForm];
Write[stmp, FortranAssign[VariableInFortran, FormulaInMathematica, \
AssignPrecision -> 16, AssignTemporary -> {t, Array}]];
Close[stmp];
```

I'm new to the format.m package so I'm not sure what the error stems from or what can be done about it.

Comment: Looks like you need to edit your TemplateForHamiltonian notebook as explained by xzczd here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215155/363

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it didn't make any difference when I tried.